# Force set tkinter window to always have focus

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is there a way to tell Tkinter that I want some widget to **always** remain focused? I've created a minimal example that can be run to show my issue , here's an example window with small toplevel windows also overlayed:

[image]

Now if I click the upper title *tk*, the main window comes into focus and suddenly the small windows are **behind** the main window

[image]

I want to treat these smaller windows as if they are **always** in focus until the user specifically closes them. Of course this is a minimal example that is an idea behind a small subsection of my large application , is there any easy setting I can use for the toplevel that guarantees it will always remain in focus regardless of other windows? Here's the actual code that can be run to replicate this:

```
from Tkinter import *

class PropertyDialog(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, string):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        self.root = root 
        self.\
             geometry('+%d+%d' %
                      (root.winfo_pointerx(),
                       root.winfo_pointery()))
        try:
            self.tk.call('::Tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle',
                                         'style', self._w,
                                         'help', 'noActivates')
        except TclError:
            pass
        window_frame = Frame(self)
        window_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        exit_frame = Frame(window_frame, background='#ffffe0')
        exit_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True)
        button = Button(exit_frame, text='x', width=3, command=self.free,
               background='#ffffe0', highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT)
        button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        text_frame = Frame(window_frame)
        text_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        label = Label(text_frame, text=string, justify=LEFT,
                      background='#ffffe0',
                      font=('tahoma', '8', 'normal'))
        label.pack(ipadx=1)

    def free(self):
        self.destroy() # first we destroy this one
        for val,widget in enumerate(dialogs): # go through the dialogs list
            if widget is self: # when we find this widget
                dialogs.pop(val) # pop it out
                break # and stop searching
        if dialogs: # if there are any dialogs left:
            for widget in dialogs: # go through each widget
                widget.lift(aboveThis=self.root) # and lift it above the root

def bind():
    """
    toggle property window creation mode
    """
    root.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', create)


def create(event):
    """
    Create actual window upon mouse click
    """
    dialogs.append(PropertyDialog(root, 'help me'))

root = Tk()
dialogs = []
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (300,400))

Button(root, text='create', command=bind).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could [build a custom `Frame` to replace the default title bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter), and then bind it to a function that put the popups back on top.

Comment: I got it to keep the popups on top by using a recurring call to `after()` to `lift()` them all on a timer, but at this point I'm wondering if it might be better to use ordinary widgets for the popups and `place()` them in a `Canvas` or something instead of having a bunch of separate windows. Then they would certainly stay put in the main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
    if dialogs: # if there are any dialogs left:
        for widget in dialogs: # go through each widget
            widget.lift(aboveThis=self.root) # and lift it above the root
```

to this:

```
    if dialogs: # if there are any dialogs left:
        for widget in dialogs: # go through each widget
            widget.lift() # and lift it above the root
```

the widgets will stay above the main window.

EDIT:

Sorry that only half worked... the widows will stay above sometimes with that code

:-X

It was keeping the widgets on top until you closed one of them.... this code does keep the widgets on top

it uses the `self.attributes("-topmost", True)` when you spawn the windows.

Sorry again.

```
from Tkinter import *

class PropertyDialog(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, string):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        self.root = root 
        self.\
             geometry('+%d+%d' %
                      (root.winfo_pointerx(),
                       root.winfo_pointery()))
        try:
            self.tk.call('::Tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle',
                                         'style', self._w,
                                         'help', 'noActivates')
        except TclError:
            pass
        window_frame = Frame(self)
        window_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        exit_frame = Frame(window_frame, background='#ffffe0')
        exit_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True)
        button = Button(exit_frame, text='x', width=3, command=self.free,
               background='#ffffe0', highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT)
        button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        text_frame = Frame(window_frame)
        text_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        label = Label(text_frame, text=string, justify=LEFT,
                      background='#ffffe0',
                      font=('tahoma', '8', 'normal'))
        label.pack(ipadx=1)
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)

    def free(self):
        self.destroy() # first we destroy this one

def bind():
    """
    toggle property window creation mode
    """
    root.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', create)


def create(event):
    """
    Create actual window upon mouse click
    """
    dialogs.append(PropertyDialog(root, 'help me'))

root = Tk()
dialogs = []
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (300,400))

Button(root, text='create', command=bind).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That doesn't make the slightest difference.

Comment: The edited version puts the popups on top of _all_ windows, including ones from other applications. Is that desired?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose, did you want the popup windows to stay on top even when switching to a different application?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving away from `Toplevel` widgets, since those are separate windows and you're suppressing their window-like behavior. This version makes `PropertyDialog` inherit from `Frame` instead of `Toplevel`, using the `place()` geometry manager. When you click the main window, it first checks whether the widget clicked was the main window or a popup window to prevent a new popup from appearing when you close an existing one. Changed areas are marked with `#CHANGED#`.

```
from Tkinter import *

class PropertyDialog(Frame): #CHANGED#
    def __init__(self, root, string, event): #CHANGED#
        Frame.__init__(self) #CHANGED#
        self.root = root 
        try:
            self.tk.call('::Tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle',
                                         'style', self._w,
                                         'help', 'noActivates')
        except TclError:
            pass
        exit_frame = Frame(self, background='#ffffe0') #CHANGED#
        exit_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True)
        button = Button(exit_frame, text='x', width=3, command=self.free,
               background='#ffffe0', highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT)
        button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        text_frame = Frame(self) #CHANGED#
        text_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        label = Label(text_frame, text=string, justify=LEFT,
                      background='#ffffe0',
                      font=('tahoma', '8', 'normal'))
        label.pack(ipadx=1)
        self.place(x=event.x, y=event.y, anchor=NW) #CHANGED#

    def free(self):
        self.destroy()
        # other things you want to do - if there's nothing else,
        # just bind the close button to self.destroy

def bind():
    """
    toggle property window creation mode
    """
    root.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', create)


def create(event):
    """
    Create actual window upon mouse click
    """
    if event.widget is root: #CHANGED#
        dialogs.append(PropertyDialog(root, 'help me', event))

root = Tk()
dialogs = []
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (300,400))

Button(root, text='create', command=bind).pack()

root.mainloop()
```