# tkinter title frame change - struggling with event bind and functions

Tags: function, events, tkinter, frame, title

I am trying to change the color of my tkinter title frame. I'm using the structure found here [Can I change the title bar in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter/23836427)

I'm having a few problems. I"ve been tinkering with the code and researching possible solutions but feel pretty stuck.

```
Text_input_window= Tk()

def get_pos(event):
    xwin = Text_input_window.winfo_x()
    ywin = Text_input_window.winfo_y()
    startx = event.x_Text_input_window
    starty = event.y_Text_input_window

    ywin = ywin - starty
    xwin = xwin - startx


def move_window(event):
    Text_input_window.geometry("400x400"+'+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_Text_input_window, event.y_Text_input_window))
    startx = event.x_Text_input_window
    starty = event.y_Text_input_window


Text_input_window.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
Text_input_window.bind('<Button-1>', get_pos)

Text_input_window.overrideredirect(True) #removes default settings in Text_input_window
Text_input_window.geometry('460x250+300+200')

title_bar=Frame(Text_input_window, bg='SteelBlue1', relief='raised', bd=2)
```

It may be obvious but i don't really know what the person did. I've tried many permutations of indenting placing the functions in different sections - should functions always be at the very beginning?
I think this is the best version of what i've mimicked into my own. I get a window with the different color and an "x" on the top right that acutally closes. However the window doesnt' move and the error i'm getting is:

```
startx = event.x_Text_input_window
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'x_Text_input_window'
```

The ide is also showing that ywin, xwin, startx and starty aren't recognized or gray like they arent' working after the line `starty = event.y_Text_input_window`

Comment: Please provide a complete testable example. You are missing at least the imports and mainloop. That said you never add title_bar to your window. You are missing `grid()` or `pack()`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood this attribute `event.x_root`. the x_root was not because the root window was named root on the other post. That is just the attribute name regardless of what you call your root window. So use `event.x_root` instead of `event.x_Text_input_window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix 2 problems first.

1. I think you misunderstood this attribute event.x_root. the x_root was not because the root window was named root on the other post. That is just the attribute name regardless of what you call your root window. So use `event.x_root` instead of `event.x_Text_input_window`.
2. You need to actually place the Frame on the window. And if you do not have any widgets in that frame you will need to define a height so you can actually see it on the window.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
import tkinter as tk


text_input_window = tk.Tk()


def get_pos(event):
    xwin = text_input_window.winfo_x()
    ywin = text_input_window.winfo_y()
    startx = event.x_root
    starty = event.y_root

    ywin = ywin - starty
    xwin = xwin - startx


def move_window(event):
    text_input_window.geometry("400x400"+'+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root, event.y_root))
    startx = event.x_root
    starty = event.y_root


text_input_window.overrideredirect(True)
text_input_window.geometry('460x250+300+200')
text_input_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

title_bar = tk.Frame(text_input_window, height=25, bg='SteelBlue1', relief='raised', bd=5)
title_bar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')


text_input_window.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
text_input_window.bind('<Button-1>', get_pos)
text_input_window.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: That definitely helps. yes I misunderstood 'root'. I having trouble moving the window. when i move it the widgets get disoriented and my cursor goes to the top left of the window.