# tkinter - I need to Remove minimize button, not Disabled, and change colore of all bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I have this code :

```
class MainPage():
"""Main interface"""

def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.root = master # Main window
    #self.root.resizable(False, False)
    self.root.geometry('300x300')
    self.root.config(background='#bfbfbf')
```

I need to Remove minimize/maximize button, not Disabled, and change colore of all bar

[image]

**I need like that :**

[image]

Comment: Try `self.root.attributes('-toolwindow', 1)`.

Comment: Yeh I know this way, but this way remove two button , X and -, I need to remove the resizable button

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter)

Comment: just recreate them