# Tkinter make overrideredirect window appear on top of other windows when clicked from taskbar

Tags: python, tkinter

How to display a custom Tkinter window (with `overrideredirect` true) on top of other opened windows when clicking from the taskbar icon? My code below works (maximize not implemented yet) except when this Tkinter window is overlapped by other non-Tkinter windows. For instance, when this Tkinter window is situated below **two** windows (of other programs) and when called (by clicking the taskbar icon), it will take **2** clicks on that icon before this window will appear on top of those 2 windows. I want to bring my window automatically on top when its taskbar icon clicked.

I based my code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530528/19225183) answer and stitched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751762/19225183) workaround for taskbar icon. I tried searching for any Tkinter code that deals on taskbar icon click event but found nothing.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def get_pos(event):
    global xwin
    global ywin
    xwin = event.x
    ywin = event.y

def move_window(event):
    root.geometry(f'+{event.x_root - xwin}+{event.y_root - ywin}')

def quit():
    root.destroy()

#window contents
root = tk.Tk()
container = tk.Toplevel(root)
root.overrideredirect(True)
#default window dimension
root.geometry('350x150+200+200')
root.minsize(350, 150)
container.attributes("-alpha",0.0)

back_ground = "#2c2c2c"

#minimize btn binding
def onRootIconify(event): root.withdraw()
container.bind("<Unmap>", onRootIconify)
root.bind("<Unmap>", onRootIconify)
def onRootDeiconify(event): root.deiconify()
container.bind("<Map>", onRootDeiconify)
root.bind("<Map>", onRootDeiconify)


#title bar
title_bar = tk.Frame(root, bg=back_ground, bd=1,
                     highlightcolor=back_ground, 
                     highlightthickness=0)
#minimize btn
minimize_btn = tk.Button(title_bar, text='', bg=back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                         bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                         activebackground="red",
                         activeforeground="white", 
                         highlightthickness=0, 
                         command=lambda: container.wm_state('iconic'))

#maximize btn
maximize_btn = tk.Button(title_bar, text='', bg=back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                         bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                         activebackground="red",
                         activeforeground="white", 
                         highlightthickness=0, 
                         command=None)

#close btn
close_button = tk.Button(title_bar, text='', bg=back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                         bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                         activebackground="red",
                         activeforeground="white", 
                         highlightthickness=0, 
                         command= quit)

#window title
title_window = "Untitled window"
title_name = tk.Label(title_bar, text=title_window, font="Arial 12", bg=back_ground, fg="white")

#main area of the window
window = tk.Frame(root, bg="white", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground=back_ground)

txt = tk.Label(window, bg='white', text="Prototype window").pack(anchor="center")

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(fill='x', side=tk.TOP)
title_name.pack(side='left', padx=5)
close_button.pack(side='right')
maximize_btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
minimize_btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

window.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side=tk.TOP)

# bind title bar motion to the move window function
title_bar.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_window)
title_bar.bind("<Button-1>", get_pos)
#workaround to enable window dragging on window title text
title_name.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_window)
title_name.bind("<Button-1>", get_pos)
minimize_btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: minimize_btn.configure(bg='#777777'))
minimize_btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: minimize_btn.configure(bg=back_ground))
maximize_btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: maximize_btn.configure(bg='#777777'))
maximize_btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: maximize_btn.configure(bg=back_ground))
close_button.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: close_button.configure(bg='red'))
close_button.bind('<Leave>',lambda x: close_button.configure(bg=back_ground))


root.mainloop()
```

The custom window:

[image: Custom Tkinter window]

Comment: you should visit these answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72317219/18364950 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72321521/18364950 is will help you

Comment: @Coder, I'll try to extract some useful code from the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking for related answers and recommendations of Coder, I finally solved my problem. In my solution, I used the technique from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72317219/19225183) answer. My finished code does not use any invisible Tkinter window and heavily utilizes `ctypes.windll` (hence my code is *only limited* to **Windows**). The logic for minimize, maximize, and close window are finished as well.

I managed to solve the following:

- No random taskbar icon glitches when minimizing/maximizing (results from wrapping invisible window)
- No issues when bringing up the custom Tkinter window when behind other windows (like that of my problem of double-clicking the taskbar icon)

```
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ctypes import windll


def set_appwindow():
    global hasstyle
    GWL_EXSTYLE=-20
    WS_EX_APPWINDOW=0x00040000
    WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW=0x00000080
    if not hasstyle:
        hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
        style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
        style = style & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
        style = style | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
        res = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
        root.withdraw()
        root.after(10, lambda:root.wm_deiconify())
        hasstyle=True

def get_pos(event):
    global xwin
    global ywin
    xwin = event.x
    ywin = event.y

def move_window(event):
    global previousPosition
    root.geometry(f'+{event.x_root - xwin}+{event.y_root - ywin}')
    previousPosition = [root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y()]

def move_window_bindings(*args, status=True):
    if status == True:
        title_bar.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_window)
        title_bar.bind("<Button-1>", get_pos)
        title_name.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_window)
        title_name.bind("<Button-1>", get_pos)
    else:
        title_bar.unbind("<B1-Motion>")
        title_bar.unbind("<Button-1>")
        title_name.unbind("<B1-Motion>")
        title_name.unbind("<Button-1>")

def quit():
    root.destroy()

#reference: https://programtalk.com/python-examples/ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow/
def minimize(hide=False):
    hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
    windll.user32.ShowWindow(hwnd, 0 if hide else 6)

def maximizeToggle():
    global maximized
    global previousPosition
    if maximized == False:
        #maximize current window
        maximize_btn.config(text="❐")
        hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40
        windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, int(root.winfo_screenwidth()), int(root.winfo_screenheight()-48),SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
        maximized = True
        move_window_bindings(status=False)
    else:
        #restore down window
        maximize_btn.config(text="")
        hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40
        windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, previousPosition[0], previousPosition[1], int(root.minsize()[0]), int(root.minsize()[1]),SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
        maximized = False
        move_window_bindings(status=True)


#---------------------------------
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)

#window details
maximized = False
back_ground = "#2c2c2c"
dimension = (300, 300)
#------------------------------

if len(dimension) == 0:
    #default window dimension
    x = (root.winfo_screenwidth()/2)-(350/2)
    y = (root.winfo_screenheight()/2)-(250)
    root.geometry(f'350x150+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
    root.minsize(350, 150)
    dimension = (350, 150)
    previousPosition = [int(x), int(y)]

else:
    x = (root.winfo_screenwidth()/2)-(dimension[0]/2)
    y = (root.winfo_screenheight()/2)-250
    root.geometry(f'{dimension[0]}x{dimension[1]}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
    root.minsize(dimension[0], dimension[1])
    previousPosition = [int(x), int(y)]




#title bar
title_bar = tk.Frame(root, bg=back_ground, bd=1,
                     highlightcolor=back_ground, 
                     highlightthickness=0)

#window title
title_window = "Untitled window"
title_name = tk.Label(title_bar, text=title_window, 
                     font="Arial 12", bg=back_ground, fg="white")

#minimize btn
minimize_btn = tk.Button(title_bar, text='', bg=back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                         bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                         activebackground="red",
                         activeforeground="white", 
                         highlightthickness=0, 
                         command=minimize)

#maximize btn
maximize_btn = tk.Button(title_bar, text='', bg=back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                         bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                         activebackground="red",
                         activeforeground="white", 
                         highlightthickness=0, 
                         command=maximizeToggle)

#close btn
close_button = tk.Button(title_bar, text='', bg=back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                         bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                         activebackground="red",
                         activeforeground="white", 
                         highlightthickness=0, 
                         command= quit)

#hover effect
minimize_btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: minimize_btn.configure(bg='#777777'))
minimize_btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: minimize_btn.configure(bg=back_ground))
maximize_btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: maximize_btn.configure(bg='#777777'))
maximize_btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: maximize_btn.configure(bg=back_ground))
close_button.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: close_button.configure(bg='red'))
close_button.bind('<Leave>',lambda x: close_button.configure(bg=back_ground))


#main area of the window
window = tk.Frame(root, bg="white", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground=back_ground)

txt = tk.Label(window, bg='white', text="Prototype window").pack(anchor="center")

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(fill='x', side=tk.TOP)
title_name.pack(side='left', padx=5)
close_button.pack(side='right')
maximize_btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
minimize_btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
window.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side=tk.TOP)
move_window_bindings(status=True)


#ctype
hasstyle = False
root.update_idletasks()
root.withdraw()
set_appwindow()

root.mainloop()
```

Demo:

[image: Window demonstration]

If someone can transform my code into a classful syntax, please comment since I have a hard time in doing so hehe. Code optimizations are very welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on John Rey Vilbar' request/suggestion, here is his implementation wrapped as an Object-Oriented, Tkinter widget. I tried to keep the class as neutral as possible while reflecting the Tkinter widget intuition, as well as John's understanding of dll calls. I welcome any and all concerns/suggestions as I have a few "next step" ideas myself.

Very little, if any modifications to the class should be needed for everyday use. The object is designed in a fashion as to operate like a wrapper with the added benefit of resolving the WM operations.

Thank you John for the very mature coding style/disciplines and the good solution. Pleasure working with you. This has been a little bit of a frustrating pursuit. Though I am happy having found your code.

UPDATE:
10-12-2023: Added functionality to restore previous window size after maximizing

```
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow

import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import windll


class RootFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__(self.parent, **kwargs)

        self.maximized = False
        self.hasstyle = False
        self.parent.windowSize = [self.parent.winfo_width(), 
                                  self.parent.winfo_height()]

        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if key == 'highlightbackground':
                self.back_ground = val
            else:
                self.back_ground = "#2c2c2c"

        self.parent.withdraw()
        self.parent.update()
        dims = [int(x) for x in self.parent.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x')]
        dimension = (dims[0], dims[1])

        x = (self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()/2)-(dimension[0]/2)
        y = (self.parent.winfo_screenheight()/2)-250
        self.parent.geometry(f'{dimension[0]}x{dimension[1]}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
        self.parent.minsize(dimension[0], dimension[1])
        self.previousPosition = [int(x), int(y)]

        self.__ParentFrame__()
        self.__events__()
        self.loop_control()

    '''GUI Private Methods'''
    def __events__(self):
        self.title_bar.bind('<Double-1>', self.maximizeToggle)
        self.title_name.bind('<Double-1>', self.maximizeToggle)

        self.minimize_btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: self.minimize_btn.configure(bg='#777777'))
        self.minimize_btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: self.minimize_btn.configure(bg=self.back_ground))
        self.maximize_btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: self.maximize_btn.configure(bg='#777777'))
        self.maximize_btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: self.maximize_btn.configure(bg=self.back_ground))
        self.close_button.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: self.close_button.configure(bg='red'))
        self.close_button.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: self.close_button.configure(bg=self.back_ground))

    def __ParentFrame__(self):
        self.parent.overrideredirect(True)

        #title bar
        self.title_bar = tk.Frame(self.parent, bg=self.back_ground, bd=1,
                             highlightcolor=self.back_ground, 
                             highlightthickness=0)

        #window title
        self.title_window = "Untitled window"
        self.title_name = tk.Label(self.title_bar, text=self.title_window, 
                             font="Arial 12", bg=self.back_ground, fg="white")

        #minimize btn
        self.minimize_btn = tk.Button(self.title_bar, text='', bg=self.back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                                 bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                                 activebackground="red",
                                 activeforeground="white", 
                                 highlightthickness=0, 
                                 command=self.minimize)

        #maximize btn
        self.maximize_btn = tk.Button(self.title_bar, text='', bg=self.back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                                 bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                                 activebackground="red",
                                 activeforeground="white", 
                                 highlightthickness=0, 
                                 command=self.maximizeToggle)

        #close btn
        self.close_button = tk.Button(self.title_bar, text='', bg=self.back_ground, padx=5, pady=2, 
                                 bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', width=2,
                                 activebackground="red",
                                 activeforeground="white", 
                                 highlightthickness=0, 
                                 command= quit)

        # pack the widgets
        self.title_bar.pack(fill='x', side=tk.TOP)
        self.title_name.pack(side='left', padx=5)
        self.close_button.pack(side='right')
        self.maximize_btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.minimize_btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.move_window_bindings(status=True)

    '''Functional Public Methods'''
    def get_pos(self, event):
        self.xwin = event.x
        self.ywin = event.y

    def loop_control(self):
        self.parent.update_idletasks()
        self.parent.withdraw()
        self.set_appwindow()

    def maximizeToggle(self, event=None):
        if self.maximized == False:
            self.winfo_update()
            #maximize current window
            self.maximize_btn.config(text="❐")
            hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(self.parent.winfo_id())
            SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40
            windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 
                int(self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()),
                int(self.parent.winfo_screenheight()-48),
                SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
            self.maximized = True
            self.move_window_bindings(status=False)
        else:
            #restore down window
            self.maximize_btn.config(text="")
            hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(self.parent.winfo_id())
            SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40
            windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 
                self.previousPosition[0],
                self.previousPosition[1],
                int(self.parent.windowSize[0]),
                int(self.parent.windowSize[1]),
                SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
            self.maximized = False
            self.move_window_bindings(status=True)

    def minimize(self, hide=False):
       #reference: https://programtalk.com/python-examples/ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow/ 
        hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(self.parent.winfo_id())
        windll.user32.ShowWindow(hwnd, 0 if hide else 6)

    def move_window(self, event):
        self.parent.geometry(f'+{event.x_root - self.xwin}+{event.y_root - self.ywin}')
        self.previousPosition = [self.parent.winfo_x(), self.parent.winfo_y()]

    def move_window_bindings(self, *args, status=True):
        if status == True:
            self.title_bar.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_window)
            self.title_bar.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_pos)
            self.title_name.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_window)
            self.title_name.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_pos)
        else:
            self.title_bar.unbind("<B1-Motion>")
            self.title_bar.unbind("<Button-1>")
            self.title_name.unbind("<B1-Motion>")
            self.title_name.unbind("<Button-1>")

    def quit(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

    def set_appwindow(self):
        GWL_EXSTYLE=-20
        WS_EX_APPWINDOW=0x00040000
        WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW=0x00000080
        if not self.hasstyle:
            hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(self.parent.winfo_id())
            style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
            style = style & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
            style = style | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
            res = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
            self.parent.withdraw()
            self.parent.after(10, lambda:self.parent.wm_deiconify())
            self.hasstyle=True

    def winfo_update(self):
        """Update geometry() information, return None"""
        self.parent.windowSize = [self.parent.winfo_width(),
                                  self.parent.winfo_height()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")

    root_frame = RootFrame(root, bg="white", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="#2c2c2c")
    root_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    
    txt = tk.Label(root_frame, bg='white', text="Prototype window")
    txt.pack(anchor="center")

    def resize():
        root.geometry("500x650")
        
    rsz = tk.Button(root_frame, text="Resize", command=resize)
    rsz.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this code. Well appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. I am looking forward to using it myself.