# hidden titlebar makes app not show up in task switcher?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple tkinter app and I want to hide the titlebar. I am doing that via:

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

and that works fine. However, the resulting window has no icon in the taskbar and when switching the windows using Alt + Tab the window does not appear. I created an exe file using Pyinstaller and was hoping that would solve the issue but it doesn't. Is there a way to to fix this?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/72197214/13629335 ?

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was partially solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73001768/tkinter-make-overrideredirect-window-appear-on-top-of-other-windows-when-clicked (only for windows though)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the title bar of a Tkinter window, we can use wm_attributes('type', 'value') method by specifying the type of property. In the following example, we will use 'fullscreen', a Boolean value that removes the title bar of the window.

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("700x350")

label= Label(win, text="Hello world", font= ('Helvetica 14 bold'), foreground= "red3")
label.pack()

win.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'True')
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as the app is not fullscreen anymore.

Comment: try ```tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)```