# How to change the tkiner window border color?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, border

I need to change the color of the Tkinter window border-color in windows 10 python. The border is shown in the image below.

[image]

I found a command that can delete the border

`root.overrideredirect(1)`

when I use this command I need to rebuild the border again but the functionality is different. So it's not an option.
Is there any way I could change the Tkinter window border color?
I only need to change the color of the border. Rebuilding the border is too much and some of the functionalities won't work properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the title bar in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter)

Comment: @FluxedScript Yes, your suggestion works too but I only need to change the border-color and when rebuilding the border some functionalities are not working properly and it's too much. Thanks for your answer it is very helpful. I'll try to use it if I can. Thanks again.

Comment: @SumethSathnindu-Lucifer You can not change the color of the title bar since it is something added by the OS, `tkinter` has no idea about it. You will have to rebuild it.

Comment: @AST It seems I have to rebuild the border from the scratch. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you cannot change the color of the border as it is created by the `OS` and it changes device-to-device. But you can use `overrideredirect(1)` to cancel the border. And to exit the window, you can use the `destroy()` command.