# How can I add new button to the control of default window manager in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, window

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root=Tk()
root.title("Program")
root.geometry('500x300')
root.mainloop()
```

[image: My Window]

This is my window and I want to add new button like here:
[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you want to edit the title bar, the way you want with Tkinter, you will have to turn off the title bar and rebuild all those methods from scratch. [Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter)

Comment: Thanks for this comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, You can't add a button to the title bar in Tkinter. if you want to do that you have to build your own title bar using Tkinter widgets.