# tkinter macos: Is there a way to change the color of the titlebar?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

The title pretty much explains what I need done, I'm not sure if its even possible, but I cannot figure out a way to change the title bar color in macOS. An example would be like how the google chrome or discord titlebar is completely different from the default.

Example:

[image: this is the example image]
[image: this is the example image]

Comment: I don't see any difference in the title bar color in your example image. Regardless, there is no official documentation to support changing the color of the title bar on any OS. There a numerous ways of faking it, if you research the topic. See [Can I change the title bar in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter) for some examples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found my answer, It was something I saw a lot and tried before but it wasn't working because I was using python3.8. Once i downloaded 3.9 it worked like a charm.

```
root.overrideredirect(1) 
root.overrideredirect(0)
```