# Tkinter just switch title bar to dark theme

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to change the title bar but just switch it to dark mode? Without creating a frame and all, just switch it to dark?

Light title bar:

[image]

Dark title bar:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

list of themes for tkinter is here:  https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes

There is a whole variety of standard dark themes even before customisation of other themes...

Here is a code example:

```
from tkinter import ttk  # Normal Tkinter.* widgets are not themed!
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

# light themes
# window = ThemedTk(theme="arc")
# window = ThemedTk(theme="kroc")
# window = ThemedTk(theme="ubuntu")

# dark themes
# window = ThemedTk(theme="black")
window = ThemedTk(theme="equilux")

ttk.Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.destroy).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

If it it just the title bar (and not the theme) that you are wishing to change then this post covers it:

[Can I change the title bar in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter)

Comment: ttk theme cannot change color of window title bar which is what OP wants.

Comment: @acw1668 i read it as switch to dark mode, but have also included a link to the title bar itself:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter