# Is there a way to change the color of the top frame of Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I've been trying to find ways in changing the color of the top frame in the program that I've created.

[This is what I'm trying to replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kgIU.png)

The only thing I can change at the moment is the background.

My current code is

```
root (Tk)
root.title("CIG 5.0")
root['background'] = '#81cdc6'
```

Comment: I believe the only way to remove it completely and recreate it from scratch. See the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter for more details.

Comment: Typo error `root (Tk)`) should be `root = Tk()`

Comment: Tkinter doesn't provide any way to change the color of the frame added by the OS.

Comment: There is a possibility shared by @[atlasologist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275008/atlasologist) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23836427/12621346)