# How to edit style of ListBox in ttk Combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello i have code like this:

```
#TComboboxStyle

mystyle.theme_settings("MyAppStyle", settings={
"TCombobox": {"configure": {"background": "#3d3d40",
                            "foreground": "#9c9c9f",
                            "arrowcolor": "#9c9c9f",
                            "fieldbackground": "#3d3d40",
                            "relief": "flat",
                            "arrowsize": 15},
              "layout": [('Entry.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                  [('Combobox.downarrow', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': 'ns'})]})]},
"TScrollbar": {"configure": {"background": "#525252",
                             "foreground": "#0000ee",
                             "troughcolor": "#9f9f9f",
                             "relief": "flat",
                             "arrowcolor": "#9f9f9f"},
               "layout": [('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough', {'sticky': 'ns', 'children': [
    ('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]}})
```

and this:

```
    mod_info = ScrollTextBox(self)
    mod_info.xscroll.configure(style='Arrowless.Horizontal.scrollbar')
    mod_info.yscroll.configure(style='Arrowless.Vertical.scrollbar')
    mod_info.txt.configure(width=50, font=('Roboto/Roboto_Bold.ttf', '18', 'bold'),
                           foreground="#969698", background="#3d3d40")
    mod_info_choose_mod = ttk.Combobox(self, font=('Roboto/Roboto_Bold.ttf', '20', 'bold'))
    mod_info_choose_mod.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.font', ('Roboto/Roboto_Bold.ttf', '20', 'bold'))
    mod_info_choose_mod.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.background', "#3d3d40")
    mod_info_choose_mod.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.foreground', "#9c9c9f")
    mod_info_choose_mod.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground', "#33393f")
    mod_info_choose_mod.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground', "white")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How u can see, ListBox has border_color is it possible to change this color, or delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ttk::combobox popdown listbox cannot be configured using
> ttk::style nor via the widget configure command.

[https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.html#:~:text=entry%20select%20foreground.-,The%20ttk%3A%3Acombobox,-popdown%20listbox%20cannot](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.html#:%7E:text=entry%20select%20foreground.-,The%20ttk%3A%3Acombobox,-popdown%20listbox%20cannot)

Comment: Is there other way to edit this? I read this page, but can’t understand what i need to do:(

Comment: @Kynomi For Windows 11, you can try modifying the following solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter/75050180#75050180.