# I am trying to change the title bar color of my Tkinter application using the following code:

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, user-interface, tkinter

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from ctypes import windll, byref, sizeof, c_int

app = ctk.CTk(fg_color='#FF00FF')
app.geometry('300x200')

# Get the current window
HWND = windll.user32.GetParent(app.winfo_id())

# Define the RGB color (e.g., Red: 255, Green: 0, Blue: 0)
titleColor = 0x0000FF  # This represents a blue color

# Use the correct attribute code (DWMWA_TITLE_COLOR) to set the color
attribute = 19
windll.dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(HWND, attribute, byref(c_int(titleColor)), sizeof(c_int))
```

However, the title bar color is not changing. I am running Windows 10 and I have the latest version of the customtkinter library installed. What could be the problem?

I tried using different attributes and still i couldn't get any solutions regard this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the title bar in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter)

Comment: no!, its not upto my expectations, im using customtkinter

Comment: customtkinter is just a library built on top of tkinter. It has the same limitations of tkinter.

Comment: ahh, ru sure about that. Yes it has same feature as tkinter,  i cant change the titlebar's color. In tkinter its very old!

Comment: do u know the solution or not?

Comment: just dont put ur trap over here

Comment: CustomTkinter is a based on Tkinter and can be used in combination with it. So changing the title bar from the operating system feels like the wrong approach, since Tkinter already has the functionality that you are probably looking for.

Comment: ah yes, but its not modern r8

Comment: If `tkinter` doesn't have the features you need, consider using a different UI framework. QT is also an option if you still want to use Python.

Comment: @Prezt that sacrifices a lot of things like letting the user smoothly resize the window or the window being on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt `tkinter` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter):

[image: customtkinter]

Code:

```
import customtkinter as ctk


def move_window(event):
    app.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root, event.y_root))


app = ctk.CTk()
app.overrideredirect(True)
app.geometry('300x200')
title_bar = ctk.CTkFrame(app, bg_color='blue', fg_color='blue')
close_button = ctk.CTkButton(title_bar, text='X', command=app.destroy, width=40)
window = ctk.CTkCanvas(app)
title_bar.pack(expand=True, fill=ctk.X, side=ctk.TOP)
close_button.pack(side=ctk.RIGHT)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=ctk.BOTH)
title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This sacrifices a lot of things like being able to drag the window around (easy to code), being able to resize the window (hard to code), and the window not being on the taskbar/not being able to alt-tab to the window. That is probably why OP said that the code from that question you linked isn't up to thier expectations

Comment: yea thats the exact reason i said it doesn't meet my expectations. Do you anyother way ?

Comment: @ganeshmurthy Look at [my project](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/tree/main/src/bettertk). The resizing isn't smooth but I managed to solve the other problems. It's a lot of (bad) code and I have no clue how to integrate it into `customtkinter`. If you are worried about the alt-tab/task manager only look at [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/blob/1f81457fa8288f247db9d944dfbea22c2136613d/src/bettertk/notitlebartk_win.py#L121) function.