# How to remove white lines around application tabs?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, ttk

How to remove white lines around `ttk.Notebook` `Tab` window? I want a similar color as the main window.

[image: Screenshot showing white lines]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
win=tk.Tk()
win.geometry("800x600")

win.title("Login and sinup")
canvas=tk.Canvas(win,bg="#303030",width=800,height=600)
canvas.pack()

tabs=ttk.Notebook(canvas)
tabs.pack()
tab1=tk.Frame(tabs,width=650,height=550,bg="#303030")
tabs.add(tab1,text="            New            ")
tabs.place(x=100,y=100)
tabs.config()


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Tkinter: How to change the windows border color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251016/python-tkinter-how-to-change-the-windows-border-color)

Comment: Looks all ***similar***, [edit] your question and explain more detailed.